# How can I move through words when typing a command in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm

I'm in Lion

with iTerm2, Zsh and Oh-My-Zsh

but I cannot move through words when pressing: ALT+left arrow or CMD+left arrow or something

instead, when I press "ALT+right arrow" it prints [C
and when I press "SHIFT+ALT+left arrow" it prints D0

how I can config iTerm2 to behave like any other program when moving through words?

Comment: solution a possible solution for this http://shadowfiend.posterous.com/backwards-word-forwards-word-and-kill-word-in

Comment: fespinozacast: the link no longer works. Do you remember what was the solution for your question?

Answer (score 15):

I finally found the solution to this problem here: https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda. The necessary steps are shown below:

1. Go to Preferences, Profile, Keys.
2. Set your left ⌥ key to act as an escape character.
3. Locate the current shortcut for ⌥ ← or create a new one, with the following settings:

   - Keyboard Shortcut: ⌥←
   - Action: Send Escape Sequence
   - Esc+: b
4. repeat for the ⌥→ keyboard shortcut with the following settings:

   - Keyboard Shortcut: ⌥→
   - Action: Send Escape Sequence
   - Esc+: f

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked pages change.

Comment: I did include the essential parts of the solution in the answer I posted in SuperUser. I understand what you say, but I was wondering if it would still apply when you are linking to an answer in a StackExchange website.

Another reason I didn't include the solution steps here is because my two answers would have come out identical, even tough they are in different SE sites. What's the preferred way of doing things in a situation like this?

Comment: Perhaps one of the questions is in the wrong site. Should I flag it, instead of providing the same answer for both?

Comment: I provided the necessary steps for the solution, so the answers remains useful if the linked article ever goes down.

Answer (score 5):

The default is on Control-left Control-right. To customize, edit preferences/Keys and associate the escape code to some other hotkey of your choice

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Open your profile and under *Keys* tab, use *Natural Text Editing* option.

Answer (score 3):

To make option-left and option-right move through words in iTerm 2, add

```
bindkey -e
bindkey '\e\e[C' forward-word
bindkey '\e\e[D' backward-word
```

to `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh, or add

```
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

to `~/.inputrc` if you use bash.

Control-left would be `\e[1;9D` in iTerm 2 and `\e[1;5D` in Terminal, and control-right would be `\e[1;9C` in iTerm 2 and `\e[1;5C` in Terminal.

To see the escape sequence for a key combination, run `cat -v` and then press the key combination.