# Terminal shortcut keys

Tags: snow-leopard, terminal, keyboard

I've recently immigrated from Ubuntu to Mac OSX Snow Leopard. I use the terminal (iterm2) extensively, and I am a great fan of shortcut keys.

The standard shortcut keys (which work in any GUI textbox) are:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> Jumps to first character in line
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> Jumps to last character in line
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> Moves one word forward
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> Moves one word backward

How can I impose these shortcuts in iterm (or terminal)?

Are there any standard key bindings for these operations in Mac I should know and use?

Comment: iTerm > Prefs > Keys lets you customize your keybindings and shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard shell shortcuts (`M-` = meta = option or esc, `C-` = control):

- `M-b` and `M-f` correspond to <kbd>⌥←</kbd> and <kbd>⌥→</kbd>
- `C-a` and `C-e` correspond to <kbd>⌘←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘→</kbd>

<kbd>⌥←</kbd> and <kbd>⌥→</kbd> are bound to `M-b` and `M-f` by default on Lion's Terminal. On 10.6 you'll have to add them manually:

[image]

I haven't found any way to reassign <kbd>⌘←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘→</kbd> in Terminal.

Comment: +1 Thanks. What does `\033b' stand for? Do you know how can I change this on iterm?

Comment: A few other useful shortcuts:

`C-w` will kill the previous word.

`C-k` will kill from the current cursor point to the end of the line.

`C-y` will yank back what was previously killed.

Comment: The '\033' is an escape sequence for the "escape key" on the keyboard, which is essentially the meta key that @Lri mentioned.  So '\033b' is essentially `M-b` and '\033f' is essentially `M-f`.  See, for example, http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100716230217548

Answer (score 0):

For iTerm2 you can customize hotkeys easily. A similar question was asked here

[How can I move through words when typing a command in iTerm2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/how-can-i-move-through-words-when-typing-a-command-in-iterm2/38983#38983)

Answer (score 0):

You'll also find Ctl-e (end of line), Ctl-a (start of line), and Esc-d (delete word from cursor) work nicely in terminal and other apps, too (along with Ctl-k and Ctl-y mentioned above), as does repeat-letter (Esc-NNN d; Esc-22 d for example to output 22 letter d's). In fact, most of the keyboard shortcuts I've tried from other Unix distributions have worked in OS/X.